# How to define hyperlink destination while cross referencing a figure in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, office365

When I click on a cross reference to a figure created in MS Word, the PDF reader always position the figure caption at the top of the reader screen.

This creates a nuisance when PDF reader is used to read the document, because as per requirement, the figure caption **HAS** to be below the figure and when the reader clicks on the hyperlink, the caption is placed at the top of the screen, hiding the figure being actually referenced.

see [document position after clicking the cross reference hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QX9L.png)

Is there any way to remedy this issue?

Regards

Comment: That depends on the PDF reader. Which one?

Comment: Well I am using Adobe reader, but I have also checked this issue with Sumatra PDF reader, and various other PDF reader on Android. The problem exists there too

Comment: Android questions should be asked on [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I meant that I have checked Adobe reader and Sumatra PDF reader on my windows PC AND other PDF readers on Android too. My main concern is to resolve the issue on PC, but the android comment was to emphasize the issue is observed on other platforms too. Again, I apologize for my ambiguous reply